# How to maintain two different versions of NPM and Node? How can I make an Angular installation specific to one project only?

Tags: node.js, angular, ionic-framework, npm

I have to work on two different projects based on NPM and Node. Old one was using Ionic and new one needs Angular only. Earlier only one project was there so the setup for it was just Ionic-related. Now I have to set up a new project in the same laptop with Angular. The problem is I may need some different NPM or Node version. Not sure how I can set up Node, NPM and Angular CLI for a new project which won't break my old Ionic project.

As much as I know NPM and Node using '-g' flags gets installed in global level (same for all the projects in same system). Am I right? Is there any way that my earlier project setup (versions of NPM and Node and Ionic) won't be changed but new project will have setup in its own folder only?

Comment: One option for this is [nvm](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm).

Comment: Yes, you can just install angular with node in a seperate folder for the new project and avoid the "-g" flag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use NVM:

> nvm is a version manager for node.js, designed to be installed
> per-user, and invoked per-shell. nvm works on any POSIX-compliant
> shell (sh, dash, ksh, zsh, bash), in particular on these platforms:
> unix, macOS, and windows WSL.

https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm

Comment: I am on Windows and I use `nvm-windows` as the alternative. https://github.com/coreybutler/nvm-windows

Comment: Thank you guys, I never knew about this concept of nvm. It helped!